# python regex find multiple matches with findall

Tags: python

I need to find 2  regex patterns , but i am not finding away to make it work

i have a variables that could be one of those (just example the are more )

```
repository = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support 7.2"

repository = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
```

i need to find both repositories with that patterns:

```
regex_rhel = 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux' + " " + str(major_version)

regex_eus = 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support' + " " + str(rhel_ver)
```

i have tried with findall ,but getting:

```
eus_latest_repos = re.findall(r'"Red Hat Enterprise Linux' + " " + str(major_version)|('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support' + " " + str(rhel_ver),repository))
                    print(eus_latest_repos)


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Can you post your required output?

Comment: At least you use bitwise `or` operator on string and tuple - note, that `|` is outside of the string. That's why you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you need a regex to extract the repo from a string.

**Demo:**

```
import re
repository = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support 7.2"
repository = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"


s = "sadasdjkasdflsdfsdf;ljk lsjdlsdfj Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support 7.2 kjshdklsdhksdjf sdfdfdfgdfg Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 sdfsdfkl;dfjsgsdfg adfadsfladjksfds"


print(re.findall("Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support\s+\d*\.?\d+|Red Hat Enterprise Linux\s+\d+", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support 7.2', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7']
```